# Which layout do you suggest

Tags: android, layout

Here is a video of my app:
It's currently using absoluteLayout, and since absoluteLayout is deprecated i decided to change my layout.

So what Layout do u suggest using for this app?
Please see the part of the video, that the game has started, that's the only part with absolutelayout.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"You can achieve much the same layout by using a FrameLayout  instead, and setting layout_margin attributes of the children. This approach is more flexible and will yield better results on different screens."

Answer (score 2):

It really depends if you want your UI to flow in a linear fashion or not. The majority of the time I use RelativeLayout with some instances of LinearLayout here and there. Relative seems to me the most flexible for me.